# Create worksheets based on lists

Tags: vba, list

I am stuck at the following problem:

I am going through a certain range trough each item and then trying to create a new worksheet each time there is a new name in the range. (The range has several rows with the same name)

I am getting the range with the following code:

```
Set r = Range("a6", Range("a6").End(xlDown))

For Each Item In r
    If Item.text[i]==item.text[i-1] Then create worksheet 
Next Item
```

I can't figure out how to program the for each

Can anyone give a good suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think Item is a restricted name.

Second in vb `==` is not what other languages use.

Third `offset(row,Column)` will move up/down/left/right

```
Dim r as range, rng as range
Set r = Range("a6", Range("a6").End(xlDown))

For Each rng In r
    If rng <> item.offset(-1) Then 
        dim ws as worksheet 
        set ws =worksheets.add
        ws.name = rng
    end If
Next rng
```

Comment: This works so well. Is there also a way to copy the whole content of the row from a1 to....xx and paste it to the according tabs. 

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
Set r = Range("a6", Range("a6").End(xlDown))

For Each Item In r
    If Item.text[i]==item.text[i-1] Then 'this line has errors, but I'll let you fix it
        Set NewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    End If
Next Item
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub aAddworksheet()


Dim rRange As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Set rRange = ws.Range("A1:A10")



i = 1
For Each Item In rRange

Debug.Print Item(i)
If i > 1 Then

    If Item(i).Value = Item(i - 1).Value Then
        Set NewSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add()
    End If
    End If

i = i + 1
Next Item

End Sub
```